# Choose random column value between rows with same ID

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

I'm a beginner with SQL and I have to do a saved query in Informatica Cloud for a connection with a SQL Server database.

I have a table where the rows with the same formId have the same columns except "possibleSalesman", which is a text column:

```
formId, email, possibleSalesman
1, email1, user1
1, email1, user2
1, email1, user4
2, email2, user2
3, email3, user3
3, email3, user1
```

What I need, is to get one row for each id and pick "possibleSalesman" randomly.

For example:

```
1, email1, user4
2, email2, user2
3, email3, user3
```

I found kind of a similar question but the solution wouldn't help me because there are a few restrictions in Informatica:

- Only SELECT statements
- Can't use asterisk to select all columns
- Can't use conversion functions
- Can't use COUNT function

If someone could help me I would be very grateful!

Comment: Please explain why you have those four limitations.

Comment: Those are the restrictions in Informatica Cloud to configure a saved query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    FormId
    ,Email
    ,possibleSalesMan
FROM
    (
    SELECT
      FormId
      ,Email
      ,possibleSalesMan
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FormId ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RowNumber
    FROM
       TableName) t
WHERE
    t.RowNumber = 1
```

In SQL Server 2008+ you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function and `NEWID()` to achieve a random order and then select the result where `ROW_NUMBER() = 1`.

Comment: Thanks! That works great in the DB but in Informatica Cloud I still get an error: Unsupported database query. Only select statements are allowed in the query.

Comment: that is only a select statement.....it is more than likely an issue with the functions ROW_NUMBER() and NEWID() that are used, but if that is the case then this is not being passed to the SQL server and the sql-server tag should be removed from your post